# Break letters of second child div

Tags: html, css

I have one requirement, where I need to apply width to the parent element which is equal to the first child element's width. This can be easily achieved using `display: inline-block` or `float: left` to the parent element if it has only one child element. But I have more than two child elements in a div. Something like this:

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/jxw4q/)**

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="first">first</div>
    <div class="value">valuevalue</div>
</div>
```

Right now, If I apply `display: inline-block` to the parent element, then it is having the width of the second child element.

[image]

To not happen this,  I tried `break-word`, `word-break` css properties on the second child element but still no use.

What I am trying to get is illustrated in the following screenshot:

[image]

Some important points:

- width of the parent element should be equal to the first child element.
- height of the parent element should be equal to sum of all the child elements.
- I don't know the width of the first child element.
- (EDIT) The first child element has some fixed width and height. I don't know these values.

I want to do this using just css. css3 is welcome. (*I know how to do this using javascript*)

Comment: Do you have to keep this exact DOM structure?

Comment: Your second requirement "height of the parent element should be equal to the second/last child element" seems to imply that the `.value` element should somehow determine the height of the parent container, which seems to also imply that the parent container should ignore the height of the `.first` element.  Please clarify, thank you.

Comment: @itay yes but if you have any closest solution with less changes then I can think about it :).  What I have actually in my project is a parent element with list of child elements.

Comment: @MarcAudet I was actually just meant that the parent should increase height automatically based on the no. of children elements. I will update my post.

Comment: Do you want the `.first` element to be visible?

Comment: @MarcAudet yes... I just want to break letters of second child div.. there must be some way which I am missing. or there may be no way using just css or css3.

Comment: Okay, so the width of the `.first` will determine the width of the parent block and all the subsequent sibling child elements, and contribute to the overall height of the parent block.

Comment: @MarcAudet yes exactly..

Comment: The first element is image? text? or can by anything ?

Comment: @aleation yes, but mostly it is an image.

Comment: I don't think that it can be done using Pure CSS only. you may have something similar.. but not exactly what your asking for.

Comment: I Got EXACTLY what you want, with less code, pure CSS, but it's CSS3, it's not too cross-browser :( see my answer, it won't work for you but it will in future so I posted it as it's interesting xD

Comment: @aleation it is working here. I am on chrome version 29.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Achieve this easily with CSS3's new intrinsic and extrinsic width values(min-content in this cas), although, it's not supported on IE, so it's not an viable option but I will just post this as it's interesting that we will be able to do that in the future:

http://jsfiddle.net/S87nE/

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="first">first</div>
    <div class="value">valuevaluevalue</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    width: -moz-min-content;
    width: -webkit-min-content;
    width: min-content;
}
.first {
    width: 50px;    /* I don't know this width */
    height: 50px;    /* I don't know this height */
    background-color: grey;
}

.value{
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

---

I guess in the worst case you could use this for newer browsers and JS for IE and older versions.

Reference:

- http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-sizing/#width-height-keywords
- http://demosthenes.info/blog/662/Design-From-the-Inside-Out-With-CSS-MinContent

Comment: Yeah you got it buddy. Where were you all this time... ?  Thanks alot man :D.

Comment: I was researching for the entire two past hours, because what you wanted to do interested me for my site xD

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, the layout style for a HTML snippet like:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="first">first</div>
    <div class="value">firstvaluevalue</div>
    <div class="value">second value value</div>
    <div class="value">third valuevalue</div>
    <div class="value">valuevalue on the fourth line</div>
</div>
```

is achievable using the following CSS:

```
.main {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    position: relative;
    width: 50px;
}
.first {
    width: 50px; /* I don't know this width */
    height: 50px; /* I don't know this height */
    background-color: grey;
}
.value {
    word-break: break-all;
    margin: 1.00em 0;
}
```

as shown in: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/tPjem/

However, I had to set the width of `.main` to that of the `.first` element in order to get the `word-break` property to take effect.

The CSS rendering problem here is that you want the width of the `.value` siblings to be equal to the unknown width of `.first`, which cannot be done with CSS alone.

CSS rendering is essentially a one-pass top-to-bottom algorithm which means that parent elements cannot inherit values from child elements (tables have a multi-pass algorithm but this won't help in this case). This may change in future versions of CSS, but for the we need to design according to these limitations.

The JavaScript/jQuery solution is to get the width from `.first` and apply it to `.main` and bind that to a window re-size action.

In some ways, this problem seems to make sense if `.first` contains an image which would have an intrinsic height and width.  If this were the case, it might make sense to set the width of `.main` to a reasonable value and then scale the image in `.first` to fill the width of the `.main` block.

Without knowing more about the actual content, it is hard to come up with alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Look at my latest comment for the Fiddle link. I changed some things in the html too. Did set the value div inside the first div to use it's width and added word-wrap to the value div.

```
.main {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    position: relative;
}
.first {
    width: 50px;  /* I don't know this width */
    position: relative;
    background-color: grey;
}

.first p {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.value {
    max-width: 100%;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="first">
        <p>first</p>
        <div class="value">valuevalue</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jxw4q/12/

Comment: I can't change the width of the first child element. Actually, I don't know the width of it. read my post again. the last points.

Comment: you are giving width to the parent element.. The parent element must have width which is equal to the first child element (and I don't know this **fixed** width). I am getting sense this is not possible even using css3 now.

Comment: you have made many changes in HTML.. which I can't do here.. BTW, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Why can't you change the html? It'll solve your question as I changed my first answer :)

Comment: Lolz man, you changed it completely. you are giving width to the parent element which is in your case `.first` and you are not assigning any width or height to the first child element which is `p` in your case. the main issue here is that I don't know the width and height of the first child element.

Comment: +1'ed to hide the downvote. I don't want any posts with less than 0 in my thread (just joking).... :D

Answer (score 0):

***Important***
this answer may not be useful for you, but can help other user who have a similar problem.

you can have the same look as you desire, but without really stretching the parent height. by using `position:absolute;` on the second `div`.

Notice: if the parent don't really stretch, it causes problems.
for example, content that will come directly after the parent, will be showed after the `.first` element. causing an overlap.

you still can use this for cases where this is the only content in the page, and you want the second div to adjust his width to the first.

(*I don't think that this is your case, but maybe it will help other user who might stumble into that question.*)
anyway, I think that your only option is to use a **Script**.

For those who fall under the use-case I've described, Here's a [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/CXWmc/)

**HTML:** (no changes here)

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="first">First div set the width</div>
    <div class="value">second fiv should wrap if bigger then first</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.main
{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.first
{
    background-color: gray;
}
.value
{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: cornflowerblue; /* moved here */
}
```

Comment: This works great for two child elements but not for more than two. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/CXWmc/1/). Anyway, I realized this ain't possible with just css. Thanks.

Comment: I agree with you. thats why I said it wont be good.. unless its for a very specific use-case. I wrote this answer only for future askers who **might** fall into that use-case category.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to achieve it without a little help of javascript. Imagine the the following markup and css :

```
<div class="main">
       <div class="first content">first</div>
       <div class="second content">valuevalue</div>
</div>
```

and then the following css :

```
.main{
    background-color : red;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 50px;
}
.first{
    background-color : blue;
}
.second{
    background-color : green;
}
.content{
     word-break: break-word;
}
```

Now all you gotta do is to set the max-width of your .main div to be equal to your first element and add the content class to each element. I suppose you are adding your elements dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution!!

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="first">first</div>
    <div class="value">valuevalue</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:1px;
    display:table;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
.first {
    width: 50px;    /* I don't know this width */
    height: 50px;    /* I don't know this height */
    background-color: grey;
    display: inline-block;
}
.value {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jxw4q/15/)

[Related link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21773325/1577396)