# div{display:table;} doesn't stretch up div to fit image

Tags: css, image, width

I've images and captions and I'd like the captions to be no wider than the images. [This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RubenGeert/t9RHu/2/) shows a working example.

The basic trick here is

```
div.img{
overflow:hidden;
width:1px;
display:table;
}
```

It seems that `display:table;` causes the div to stretch up to the image width, even though the width was specified as 1px. I'm using this because the image widths vary and may stretch depending on viewport width as well.

So far so good. However, on a local page, the trick is not working. The `div` really shows up as 1px in width. Oddly, a (seemingly) comparable `div` *does* show the proper behavior. I'm not sure how to demonstrate the problem page because it's a local page with quite some html/css and images... I'll be more than delighted to come up with screen shots or (a ton of) css if that may help debugging.

I don't immediately see differences between the functioning and the non functioning `div`s in the Firefox console. Does anybody have a clue what to look at?

[image]

Comment: P.s. an entirely different approach to the image caption width would be very welcome too as long as the caption can be left out altogether without breaking anything.

Comment: once try using `max-width` instead..

Comment: Found the problem: the image just wasn't loading. The tiny "image" displayed by the browser is the image border that's still present with the image itself absent. Didn't come to mind that that could be the culprit but anyway: problem solved :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution using CSS3:

```
div.img {
    width: -moz-min-content;
    width: -webkit-min-content;
    width: min-content;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/t9RHu/5/)

[related link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18960176/1577396)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But in my test page, the behavior has become even weirder now. I'll add a screen shot to my OP.

Comment: The `div` width is now reported as `480px` and the image width as `80px` (which is correct, see screenshot in OP). However, the image shows up as some `2px` instead.

Comment: @RubenGeert not completely clear but you are giving a width to the `div.img` through this style `div.man > div{width: 30em;}` that is how `480px` is coming I think. if you remove that style then it should work fine I suppose.

Comment: it turned out to be an entirely different problem but it's been solved. Thank you for your assistance, it's appreciated! P.s. good catch on the `30em`. That's normally overridden for `div.img` but I temporarily disabled it in order to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: @RubenGeert yeah np :)