# Div should be the width of its children, while the other child should wrap

Tags: html, css

I have a simple container that will hold some dynamic content. It should look something like this:

```
--------------------     -------------------------------
| This is the title |    | This is a much longer title |
--------------------     -------------------------------
| This is the text  |    | This is the text that will  |
| that will be put  |    | be put onto multiple lines  |
| onto multiple     |    | depending on the width of   |
| lines depending   |    | the title                   |
| on the width of   |    -------------------------------
| the title         |
--------------------
```

I want "This is the title" to set the width of the container so that it is always on one line. The other text should wrap onto multiple lines.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/richardtbell/x3p6dpyz/) to show issue.

Comment: The scenario you have mentioned and the output of the fiddle is the same. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: duplicate? [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18956530/1577396)

Comment: The text should reflow itself to the dynamic width of the title, without having to set any widths manually, I believe

Comment: The second child container should be positioned absolute but if we do so, it will come out of the parent container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works - http://jsfiddle.net/945n1ofs/

The `inline-block` on the `.container` makes it as narrow as possible, then the `white-space: nowrap` on the `.title` forces it to be as wide as it needs to be.

Then the `.container` being relatively positioned with the `.content` inside being `absolute` means that the `.content` can't affect the width of `.container` as it's outside the document flow.

Lastly, you just need to add a little `top` positioning to the child to account for the one-line title, and move the borders onto the title and child.

Comment: But the parent container will not get the height according to the child containers. check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/945n1ofs/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Richard,

You have to add some javascript

### Javascript

Include JQuery file also from [Here](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var x = $('.title').outerWidth(true); // Find width of TITLE
    $('.content').attr("style", "width:"+ x +"px"); // Assign the TITLE value to CONTENT
});
```

### CSS

```
.container {
    border: 1px solid black
}

.title {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Not needed at all, and could be done better with `.css('width', int width)`

Comment: output of "Width" vs "outerwidth" may vary... Chk this article https://forum.jquery.com/topic/width-vs-outerwidth

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can achieve this with pure CSS. But with some help of JS it can be something like this:

CSS

```
.container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}
.title {
    float: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.content {
    clear: both;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var titleWidth = $('.title').width();
   $('.title').next('.content').width(titleWidth);
});
```